# Need to update the Timestamp in Hbase based on my column own values but not default timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

In default, Hbase has the timestamp value for each row. How can we update my own timestamp value in the HBase through spark scala code while save(insert) the records from the spark Dataframe?

For Example,

```
create 'test', 'cf'

put 'test', 'row1', 'cf:a', 'value1'

put 'test', 'row2', 'cf:b', 'value2'

put 'test', 'row3', 'cf:c', 'value3'

scan 'test'

ROW COLUMN+CELL

row1 column=cf:a, timestamp=1288380727188, value=value1

row2 column=cf:b, timestamp=1288380738440, value=value2

row3 column=cf:c, timestamp=1288380747365, value=value3
```

How can we update the timestamp based on our dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the timestamp you want adding a Long at the end:
put 'test', 'row1', 'cf:a', 'value1, 1111111

If you want to update the timestamp, you only need to add the same data again (If you have VERSIONS = 1, but this is other question)